# How do I change the resolution of a window in SDL? Everything is too large

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am making a game in SDL and had an oversight of the resolution. Everything (the sprites) are too large and I want to know if I can bump up the resolution so everything is smaller without changing every sprite or modifying how the surfaces are created? Here is what I am dealing with:

[image: my game (png)]

Comment: In pure SDL2, you will have to minimize the sprites with an external library like SDL2_gfx. Maybe it is time for you to learn OpenGL which allows to do those manipulations without performance loss like SDL will.

Comment: Thanks! In my game I preload all the sprites before the main loop so minimizing them shouldn't affect performance... any further... ;)

Comment: Might be a better question for the Game Development site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SDL 2.0.0, you can use the function `SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize` [*to set a device independent resolution for rendering*](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize).

This way, you can set up your renderer with the  desired target resolution and draw everything as if you are working with that resolution.

I cite the official [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide):

> This is nice in that you can change the logical rendering size to achieve various effects, but the primary use is this: instead of trying to make the system work with your rendering size, we can now make your rendering size work with the system. On my 1920x1200 monitor, this app thinks it's talking to a 640x480 resolution now, but SDL is using the GPU to scale it up to use all those pixels. Note that 640x480 and 1920x1200 aren't the same aspect ratio: SDL takes care of that, too, scaling as much as possible and letterboxing the difference.

Please, note that you can control how scaling happens with a [bunch of hints](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryHints), as an example `SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY`.

Comment: One caution, though, `SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize()` scales each draws individually (instead of using render target). This can cause artifacts on the screen especially when you are not drawing the entire texture (eg. using sprite sheet). 

There are discussion about using render target instead of scaling each draw separately. AFAIK this is not implemented yet, and it relies on the render-to-texture functionality provided by the api/hw/platform/etc.

Comment: Interesting. I'm working on small games and usually I've not a sprite sheet, so honestly I've never seen those artifacts of which you are speaking. Anyway, if you can provide a few links, I'd be glad to integrate the response with more details. Thank you.

Comment: [This](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=10411&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=15) is one of the thread that discuss about this. Sadly the code is not there anymore, and the one mentioned the problem is me (mr_tawan in that board) so it is hardly a reference. With that said down below Sam (SDL dev) mentioned that he has acknowledged the problem and would consider solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can bumb the resolution up. It would make your sprite looks smaller if you're using fullscreen mode, just like when you adjust your monitor resolution.  When you're in Window mode, the window would get bigger but the sprite would look the same.

You can resorts to virtual resolution as @skypjack mentioned as well. One approach is to use `SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize()`, another is to do render target.

You can also resize the sprite, either online (specify the target rect which is smaller than the source), or off-line (using batch image processing tool like ACDSee or Photoshop).

In the end you'd have more space to fill.

My advise is, when you're working with graphics, try having a target resolution in mind, 1280x720 or 800x600 for example. Then designing all the asset around this resolution. In the end you will have the assets that fits well together without resorting to programming trick. Then if you run into devices with different resolution, you can use the 'virtual resolution' I mentioned above to fix it. There are a few tricks like safe-frame or letterboxing that would be needed too, but let's leave it as an advance question :-).